# What does s/(\W)/\\$1/g do in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I went over a piece of code in which a subroutine takes `video filename` as argument, and then printing it's duration time. Here I'm only showing the snippet.

```
sub videoInfo {
  my $file = shift;
  $file =~ s/(\W)/\\$1/g;
}
```

So far I understood is that it is dealing with `whitespaces` but I'm not able to break the meaning of code, I mean what is `$1` and how it will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It puts backslashes in front of non-word characters. Things like `"untitled file"` becomes `"untitled\ file"`.

As in most regular expression operations `$1` represents the first thing captured with `(...)` which in this case is the `(\W)` representing a single non-word character.

I think this is an unnecessary home-rolled version of [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).